# Change 10.28 by 1028

Tags: php

I have a problem with a string to convert in number. I am not good with this elements `!\d+!`

I used that but the apporach is not correct.

Thank you.

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $product_price[$i], $matches);
$price_extracted =  (float)implode('.', $matches[0]);
$item['normal_price'] = $price_extracted;
if ($item['normal_price'] > 800) ......
```

I have this result

```
1 299,99 $ (orginal) is converted in 1.2999 and must be 1299.99
549,99 $   (orginal) is converted in 549.99 and must be  549.99 
44,99 $  (orginal)  is converted in 44.99 and must be  44.99
```

Comment: _I used that but the apporach is not correct_ Huh? Where is the issue? What errors? What result are you expecting?

Comment: use **money_format**, i hop it will help you http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: first of all there online regex-testers: regex101.com or specifically for php: phpliveregex.com. Secondly: replace your first two lines of code with: $price_extracted = (float)(preg_replace("/,/", ".", preg_replace("/\$||\s/", "", $product_price[$i]))); From the results you wrote I assumed that the dollar sign is part of the string as well as the whitespace between 1 and 2 in the first price...

Comment: I believe you could simplify my preg_replaces with the correct regex string. But it's a pointer at least

Comment: For me It can be in any monney, Eur, $ ..; It's difficult to use money_format or to say all currency is in $ or EUR

Comment: BTW: "this elements" is actually regex. It's not so easy if you just look at a regex to know what it does. Try a regex tutorial though. It might be helpful sometime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is, that you put the digits that are not separated by anything into an array.
This means that with the first string that you provided, where the thousand dollars is seperated by a whitespace is being registered as one of these matches.

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', '1 299,99 $', $matches)   -> returns an array as follows:

$matches[0] = 1
$matches[1] = 299
$matches[2] = 99
```

If you take my approach though and first replace all whitespaces by nothing and then split the numbers into the array...:

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', preg_replace('/\s/', '', '1 299,99 $'), $matches) -> returns following array:

$matches[0] = 1299
$matches[1] = 99
```

after that you can still implode them:

```
$price_exctracted = (float)implode(".", $matches);
```

---

**EDIT**

A little explanation about preg_replace, preg_match_all and regex:

The regex '!\d+!' (I don't actually know why there would be '!' instead of '/' but if it works...) searches for digits (\d). The "+" refers to "one or more". So the line

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', 'someString', $myArray)
```

could be translated into english as follows:

```
Find all occurances of digits, be it one or more,
and put these occurances separated into one index of $myArray.
```

The second regex used in my solution, '/\s/' , is used to search for whitespaces. The "preg_replace"-function is an easy "find and replace" function concluding in:

```
preg_replace('/\s/', '', 'someString')
```

translated to english:

```
Find all occurances of whitespaces and replace them with nothing in 'someString'
```

For reference:

[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

[regex cheat sheet](https://media.cheatography.com/storage/thumb/davechild_regular-expressions.750.jpg)

Conditions can be checked on:

[PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)

Comment: Ok Kathara, Tk but if I make that preg_match_all('!\d+!', preg_replace('/\s/', $product_price[$i]), $matches);, like you can see $product_price could be affilied to $ or € or CAD ... That' my problem

Comment: With this solution you shouldn't have a problem. The only problem that you would have is, when the numbers aren't formatted the same way as here. In this solution I've only stripped the string off the spaces and it doesn't matter if it is $ or € or £ anymore. If you want to I can explain to you more detailed what happens in this line with preg_match_all.

Comment: Ok, I used but my price is 0 also I have an error with that preg_replace('/\s/', $product_price[$i]) replaced by preg_replace('/\s/', $product_price[$i], null) (3 argument mandatory). example than I need to extract price https://www.ldlc.com/navigation/galaxy+note+8/ or https://www.bestbuy.ca/fr-CA/Search/SearchResults.aspx?query=Galaxy%20note%208

Comment: Sorry I make a mistake in my last comment; Tk.